# Redux Store updated, but isn't reflected in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, redux, redux-thunk

I've been trying to pull data from a foreign exchange API, but I'm a little stumped to as why changes aren't reflected through mapStateToProps.

In essence, I'm trying to make a call to the api through an action creator. Here is the action creator.

```
export const fetchTimeData = (currency, date) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://api.fixer.io/${date}?base=${currency}`);

    const temp  = res.data.rates;
    var arr = Object.keys(temp).map(function (key) { 
      return (
          temp[key]
      ); 
    });

    var arr2 = Object.keys(temp).map(function (key) { 
      return (
          key
      ); 
    });

    var empty = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      empty[i] = {title: arr2[i], value: arr[i]};
    }

    _.remove(empty, {title: 'IDR'});
    _.remove(empty, {title: 'KRW'});
    _.remove(empty, {title: 'HUF'});

    empty.sort((a, b) => {
        var titleA = a.title.toLowerCase()
        var titleB = b.title.toLowerCase()
        if (titleA < titleB) //sort string ascending
            return -1 
        if (titleA > titleB)
            return 1
        return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
    })

    dispatch({type: FETCH_TIME_DATA, payload: empty});
  }
};
```

This action is being called from the calculateDays function in another file. The enumerateDays function returns an array of dates between the desired date and the current date. For example, ["2017-08-10", "2017-08-11", "2017-08-12", "2017-08-13", "2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-17", "2017-08-18", "2017-08-19"]

In calculateDays, the action creator is being called, which in turn is an async call to the api I'm using.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.calculateDays();
}

calculateDays() {
    var currentDate = moment();
    var hold = enumerateDays('2017-8-10', currentDate);

    var days = [];
    var firstDay = hold[0];
    var currencies;

    days = hold.map((date) => {

        var inBetween = calculateBetween(firstDay, date);
        this.props.fetchTimeData(this.props.base, date);

        console.log("this is tempData", this.props.saveTime)

        return(
            {
                currencies: 'test',
                date: date,
                days: inBetween
            }
        )
    })

}

render(){

    const margins = { top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 60 };
    const svgDimensions = { width: 1400, height: 800 };

    var data = [
      {
          "age": 39,
          "index": 0
      },
      {
          "age": 38,
          "index": 1
      },
      {
          "age": 34,
          "index": 2
      },
      {
          "age": 12,
          "index": 3
      }
  ];

  //for color, pass the array of colors to the redux store then pop off from the beginning into chartSeries

  var chartSeries = [
      {
        field: 'age',
        name: 'USD',
        color: '#ff7f0e',
        style: {
          "stroke-width": 2,
          "stroke-opacity": .2,
          "fill-opacity": .2
        }
      }
    ]

    //iterate over a list of years and calculate days from using moment
    //the data will have years, but the function down here will change it
    //set the very first index date as the "from" date in moment.js
    var x = function(d) {
      return d.index;
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <LineChart
                margins= {margins}
                width={svgDimensions.width}
                height={svgDimensions.height}
                data= {data} 
                chartSeries= {chartSeries} 
                x= {x}
            />
            {console.log(this.props.saveTime)}
        </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        saveTime: state.data.currencyTime
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DateChart);
```

Lastly, this is my reducer.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    currency: fakeData,
    currencyTime: []
}

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return {...state, currency: action.payload};
        case FETCH_TIME_DATA:
            return {...state, currencyTime: action.payload};
        default:
           return state;
   }
}
```

I've tried debugging with redux logger and I see that the action is being fired correctly https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx2Qf.jpg. However, I still get returned an empty array.

In my other similar action creator, I get the data from the api and mapeStateTo props with no problem.

I feel like I'm missing a key part of understanding how the redux store updates in the Component lifecycle, but I'm not sure what exactly. The repo is here if you would like to take a closer look https://github.com/kudou-reira/forexD3

Comment: I dont see you using currencyTime and saveTime anywhere in the component then how do you know it is not reflected? Are you doing console.log somewhere in the component to see if it is updated or not?

Comment: @Yeo Wand:  Have you find the answer? If not let me know ASAP, I'll help you!

Answer (score 3):

Have you added your reducer in your combineReducer?

Comment: Data is coming just fine in the component's `mapSTateToProps` but can't see reference to any props in the render function

Comment: Can you share your code what you've written in your mapStateToProps function? and Check Have you passed mapStateToProps to a connect i.e. export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(ComponentName)

Comment: Look for yourself https://github.com/kudou-reira/forexD3/blob/master/src/components/dateChart.js

P.S. This is not my code

Comment: My combine reducers is                                                                     
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import dataReducer from './dataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
 data: dataReducer
});                                                                                                                                   and it's connected                                                                                                      export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(DateChart);

Comment: If I add a {console.log(this.props.saveTime)} in the component, I get an empty array back.